# Pass data to macro via variable in Clojure(Script)

Tags: clojure, macros, clojurescript

Is there any trick to make this work without passing the data directly or using eval?

```
(defmacro pair-defs [data]
  (cons 'do
    (for [[k v] data]
      `(def ~k ~v))))

(def data '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)))
(pair-defs data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `data` var is defined in namespace before the macro call,you can use some namespace manipulating functions to resolve it's value by name:

```
(defmacro pair-defs [data]
  `(do ~@(for [[k v] @(ns-resolve *ns* data)]
           `(def ~k ~v))))

user> (def data [['a 10] ['b 20]])
#'user/data

user> (pair-defs data)
#'user/b
```

or to handle both literal data and data by var name:

```
(defmacro pair-defs [data]
  (let [dt (if (symbol? data) @(ns-resolve *ns* data) data)]
    `(do ~@(for [[k v] dt]
             `(def ~k ~v)))))
```

the call is expanded to the desired form: `(do (def a 10) (def b 20))`

So resolving the namespace val without dirty tricks like `eval` is totally possible, but i find it to be quite an unneeded usage of macros. For example your task is easily replaceable by plain function call.

```
(defn pair-defs1 [data]
  (doseq [[k v] data]
    (intern *ns* k v)))
```

it would work on any `data` sequence, be it local or global, literal or generated